# Looking for a new Gpu card in my budget for gaming experience

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, pc

I am building a PC with AMD FX 6300. Frankly i do not know most of the parts but as my computer hardware person said the basic pc is going to be built till 23000 INR. My pc will have 1 TB WD HDD, 8GB Ram and power cooler fan. I want a Graphics card which is best for playing almost all games either to play on low or mid settings. My budget is 14000 INR and do not know much about a graphics card results.

Can anyone suggest me what to buy?
Side note:
I have a LG 700 sxga monitor having 1024x768 resolution.

**I want a good graphics card and not a graphics card that will be best for my situation.**

Updated: In USD my budget is 195. I want a GDDR5 gpu!!

Answer (score 1):

After a brief search in hardwire.in, I recommend:
AMD: [RX 460](http://hardwire.in/home/2077-sapphire-radeon-rx-460-4-gb-nitro.html)
NVidia: [GTX 1050 Ti](https://www.theitdepot.com/details-Zotac+Geforce+GTX+1050+Ti+Mini+4GB+GDDR5+Graphic+Card+(ZT-P10510A-10L)_C45P27544.html)

Out of the two, I would go with the GTX 1050 Ti.

That way, your GPU would be decent for playing games when you upgrade to a 1080p monitor. 1440p or more would require tuning settings down.

> Converting your budget into USD, I would suggest:
>  
>  AMD: [RX 470](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/dDZ2FT/msi-radeon-rx-470-4gb-video-card-radeon-rx-470-gaming-x-4g)
>  NVidia: [GTX 1060](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/HWtWGX/evga-geforce-gtx-1060-3gb-gaming-video-card-03g-p4-6160)
>
>  Either would be more than powerful for your CPU+Monitor combination. :)

Comment: I added an extra note "budget in USD."

Comment: At worst, they stretch your budget with $4.99. Do you want other recommendations?

Comment: Yes please. If it could fit i would like to have more broad choice to build a good gaming pc

Comment: i was thinking of getting a Asus GTX 750 ti OC 2gb Gddr5. Is it good?

Comment: I'd recommend an RX 460 (470s don't fit your budget) from an Indian store, as per the edit.

Comment: Can you brief me on RX 640 vs GTX 750 ti?

Comment: And also i want a gddr5 gpu.

Comment: The RX 460 has GDDR5 memory.

Comment: Moreover, the RX 460 will blow the 750 Ti out of the water in terms of performance. It's superior on any front, plus it supports Crossfire configurations.

Comment: Any website to review the specs for RX 460?

Comment: Hold that thought! I think I found a better solution: [GTX 1050 Ti](https://www.theitdepot.com/details-Zotac+Geforce+GTX+1050+Ti+Mini+4GB+GDDR5+Graphic+Card+(ZT-P10510A-10L)_C45P27544.html)

Comment: Please tell me which stores you can and want to buy from; I am confused when it comes to India retailers.

Comment: online stores like flipkart, amazom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47461/discussion-between-fragamemnon-and-sorangwala-abbasali).